# how to minimize dependency between a form and a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, dependency-injection

In this sample code (C# winForms app) there is a `Employee` class with `SearchEmployee()` method and a `DataService` class with `GetByEmployeeID()` method. When searching for a employee, `SearchEmployee(`) method will call `GetByEmployeeID()` method to talk to database. I have minimized the dependency between `Employee` class and `DataService` class by using constructor injection. (in its simplest way with out using an Interface)

But there is a dependency between `Form` class and `Employee` class as I `new` employee object from `From` class.

Will that dependency be a problem or isn't?

If that dependency should be avoided, What is the simplest way to achieve this?

I prefer not to use a pattern like MVP as I'm not familiar with it.

```
Class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Employee newEmp = new Employee (new DataService()); //Making a dependency 
                newEmp = newEmp.SearchEmployee (txtEmployeeID.Text);
                txtEmployeeName.Text = newEmp.EmployeeName;
                txtEmployeeAddress.Text = newEmp.EmployeeAddress;
        }
}


Class Employee
{
        string EmployeeID  { get; set; }
        string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }

        DataService _DS;

        public Employee(DataService DS) //Constructor injection of dataservice object
        {
            this._DS = DS;
        }

        public Employee SearchEmployee (string employeeID)
        {
            this.EmployeeID  =employeeID;

            DataTable DT= _DS.GetByEmployeeID(EmployeeID);
            this.EmployeeName = DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            this.EmployeeAddress = DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();

            return this; //Returning an employee object to the caller
        }
}


//This class responsible for database transaction

 class DataService
    {

        public DataTable GetByEmployeeID(string employeeID)
        {
            using (SqlConnection newCon = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT..WHERE emp_id=@employeeID", newCon);
                Cmd.Parameters.Add("@employeeID", SqlDbType.varChar).Value = employeeID;
                newCon.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable results = new DataTable();
                results.Load(rdr);

                return results;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Will that dependency be a problem or isn't?*** - It's not a problem here until how you want to get things done.

***If that dependency should be avoided..?*** - Yes. Your program is having only one unit of work which is GetByEmployeeID(string employeeID). Dependency Injection(DI) is supposed to use when an employee object will need some other objects like department(which becomes dependency of employee object & will be injected via constructor pattern). In your program, dependency works like a service so there is almost no possibility that it alters its behavior depending on the caller. Also DI simplifies testing/mocking objects, testing employee object will eliminate the need of testing it's dependencies i.e. department.

***What is the simplest way to achieve this?. I prefer not to use a pattern like MVP as I'm not familiar with it.*** -
Well, simplest requires solid base/architecture, then after your program will be able to accomplish this task in quite a few lines of code. You can use ORM(object relational mapper) frameworks like Microsoft entity framework which simplifies domain/data/repository/unit-of-work part.

Comment: Ok.But what about the dependency between form and employee? In that case cant we use something like DI if that dependency too should be avoided? Apart from that , do you see any major drawbacks in my sample code? as Im trying to develop a payroll system in this way.

Comment: You can of course use entity objects(Employee in your case) in Form Class. What i would like to see is SOC(separation of concerns) as part of architecture(you are using old ado.net compare to latest ORM frameworks). Did you check [Inversion-of-control(IOC) containers/frameworks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) to implement DI out there, fyr.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a class representing an entity should contain information relevant to that entity.

Any method that belong to the management of the entity, like looking for a specific object, telling which ones contain a set of properties and the like should be in a different class.

To make my point clear:

You can have your "Employee" with only the 3 string properties and then an "EmployeeManager" which is responsible of searching for employees, containing a list with all employees, looking by id, etc.

That way, you objects will be only information carriers and you will brake the dependency between them.

In your case, it makes more sense to have the "SearchEmployee" method on the Data Service.

Comment: Ok if I have SearchEmployee() in either EmployeeManager class or in  DataService class, How should I call this method from my Form passing txtEmpID.text as an argument? Can dependency injection be used to minimize the dependency in this case? if so could you answer with code sample?